# How to use gocenter remote Artifactory repo for local dependency resolution?

Tags: go, artifactory

I am new to go and trying to use a gocenter remote repo (Artifactory 6.8) for dependency resolution. Despite setting GOPROXY env var my gocenter-cache repo remains empty.

Here's my go code.

```golang
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "github.com/naoina/go-stringutil"
)

func main() {
        var str string = "hello_world_go"
        fmt.Println(stringutil.ToUpperCamelCase(str)) //prints HelloWorldGo
}
```

The dependency I am trying to resolve is here: https://search.gocenter.io/github.com~2Fnaoina~2Fgo-stringutil/versions

Here's my GOPROXY env var:

```
$ echo $GOPROXY
https://<<my Artifactory URL>>/api/go/gocenter
```

Here's a truncated version of the gocenter repo definition. I used the [jfrog docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Go+Registry#GoRegistry-ProxyingGoCenter) for setting this up:

```
{
  "key" : "gocenter",
  "packageType" : "go",
  "url" : "https://gocenter.io/",
  "rclass" : "remote"
}
```

When I run "go get" the dependency resolves...

```
$ go get -v github.com/naoina/go-stringutil
github.com/naoina/go-stringutil (download)
```

but gocenter-cache is empty, telling me it wasn't used.

```
{
  "repo" : "gocenter-cache",
  "path" : "/",
  "created" : "2019-04-17T16:35:37.586Z",
  "lastModified" : "2019-04-17T16:35:37.586Z",
  "lastUpdated" : "2019-04-17T16:35:37.586Z",
  "children" : [ ],
  "uri" : "https://<<REDACTED>>/api/storage/gocenter-cache"
}
```

Perhaps my "go get" should have a different target? I am just using what exists in gocenter: https://search.gocenter.io/github.com~2Fnaoina~2Fgo-stringutil/versions

Any help in pointing out what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. I haven't gone into modules yet or anything like that, as I am an artifactory admin and not a go developer. I am just trying to prototype this functionality so we can help advise our users with what to do.

--UPDATE: I found https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Module_proxy_protocol and then tried this:

```
$ echo $GOPROXY; go get $GOPROXY/github.com/naoina/go-stringutil
https://<<REDACTED>>/api/go/gocenter
package https:/<<REDACTED>>/api/go/gocenter/github.com/naoina/go-stringutil: https:/<<REDACTED>>/api/go/gocenter/github.com/naoina/go-stringutil: invalid import path: malformed import path "https:/<<REDACTED>>/api/go/gocenter/github.com/naoina/go-stringutil": invalid char ':'
```

So the colon between my protocol and my url is an invalid character? Also why is it removing one of my forward slashes?

--UPDATE2:
I got "go mod init" to work, kind of:

```
$ go mod init
go: creating new go.mod: module example/hello
$ ls
go.mod  hello.go
$ go build
build example/hello: cannot load github.com/naoina/go-stringutil: cannot find module providing package github.com/naoina/go-stringutil
$ cat go.mod
module example/hello

go 1.12
$ echo $GOPROXY
https://<<REDACTED>>/api/go/gocenter
```

--UPDATE 3:

```
$ cat go.mod
module example/hello

go 1.12

require github.com/naoina/go-stringutil v0.1.0

$ go build
hello.go:6:2: cannot find package "github.com/naoina/go-stringutil" in any of:
        C:\Go\src\github.com\naoina\go-stringutil (from $GOROOT)
        C:\Users\samuelm\go\src\github.com\naoina\go-stringutil (from $GOPATH)

$ echo $GOPROXY
https://<<REDACTED>>/api/go/gocenter
```

--UPDATE 4: it appears I'm still not using modules?

```
$ go list -m all
go list -m: not using modules
```

--UPDATE 5, re: retgits
Your steps helped, but I'm still not all the way there.

```
$ find .
.
./bin
./src
./src/example.com
./src/example.com/hello
./src/example.com/hello/hello.go

$ cd src/

$ go mod init example.com/hello
go: creating new go.mod: module example.com/hello

$ cat go.mod
module example.com/hello

go 1.12

$ go get -v github.com/naoina/go-stringutil
Fetching https://<<REDACTED>>/api/go/gocenter/github.com/naoina/go-stringutil/@v/list
Fetching https://<<REDACTED>>/api/go/gocenter/github.com/naoina/@v/list
Fetching https://<<REDACTED>>/api/go/gocenter/github.com/@v/list
go get github.com/naoina/go-stringutil: unexpected status (https://<<REDACTED>>/api/go/gocenter/github.com/naoina/go-stringutil/@v/list): 404 Not Found

$ go build example.com/hello
can't load package: package example.com/hello: unknown import path "example.com/hello": cannot find module providing package example.com/hello

$ cd example.com/hello/

$ go build
build example.com/hello/example.com/hello: cannot load github.com/naoina/go-stringutil: cannot find module providing package github.com/naoina/go-stringutil
```

I am not providing credentials in my GOPROXY, because our end-users do not have accounts, we're inside a firewalled env and allow full anon read access. If we have to provide user accts then we cannot support Go.

--FINAL UPDATE:
Removing my local proxy resolved the 404 issue, retgits solution works.

Comment: Are you running the commands in a module aware Go project? In other words, does the folder you're running the commands in have a `go.mod` file? Comparing the results in my machine between running it in a Go project with a Go mod and an empty folder (not a Go project) I see the same results as you do (which is expected behavior by the Go client)

Comment: To use go mod you can do the following: `echo "module test" > go.mod; go mod tidy` . If your proxy set correctly it should work.

Comment: I do not have a go.mod file. I could not tell if that was required or not. I will try that.

Comment: I got: "go: modules disabled inside GOPATH/src by GO111MODULE=auto; see 'go help modules'". I do not have an env var "GO11MODULE" set.

Comment: see update2 for creation of my go.mod file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned you're not a Go developer so let me walk you through all the steps. I realize it might be a little overkill to some of the devs here, but it might help you.

Depending on where you've put your source code you will need to set the environment variable `GO111MODULE`. Since go 1.11 it's recommended to not put your source code in your $GOPATH anymore. If you put your code there and want to use Go modules you'll have to set the `GO111MODULE` to `true` (personally I keep all my Go code outside of the $GOPATH). On Windows you'll have to create the environment variable first and set it accordingly (and restart your terminal).

To create a Go module you'll have to run the command `go mod init <name of your module>`. In my case, I've ran the command `go mod init github.com/retgits/bla` which created a `go.mod` file with

```
module github.com/retgits/bla

go 1.12
```

Adding modules will now be as simple as running `go get`. If you want to use GoCenter or Artifactory to help resolve your modules.

To help resolve modules there are two options you might want to look at:

- Using a utility called `goc`
- Setting up a remote and virtual proxy

**Using goc**

The [goc](https://github.com/jfrog/goc) utility automatically sets GOPROXY to GoCenter, bypassing other proxies like Artifactory. The current behavior of the Go client is to look at one single proxy and fail your build if not all modules are resolved from there. `goc` will look at GoCenter first and if the module isn't in GoCenter it will get the module from its original place (like GitHub)

**Using Artifactory**

If you want to use Artifactory to resolve, and cache, your Go modules you'll have to create a remote repository with the settings for GoCenter (which are in the documentation as you mentioned). You'll have to include that remote repository into a virtual one for it to work.

**Setting GoCenter as GOPROXY**

A third option would be to only use GoCenter (the public registry created by JFrog), but that might defeat your original question:

```
export GOPROXY="https://gocenter.io"
go get -v github.com/naoina/go-stringutil
```

No matter which of the options you choose it will update the `go.mod` to

```
module github.com/retgits/bla

go 1.12

require github.com/naoina/go-stringutil v0.1.0 // indirect
```

The `indirect` is because I've not yet created a `.go` file with the code that uses this import.

If I now create a `main.go` sample with

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/naoina/go-stringutil"
)

func main() {
    str := stringutil.ToSnakeCase("HelloWorld")
    fmt.Println(str)
}
// Running go run main.go would result in
// hello_world
```

it will remove the `indirect` from the go.mod file because I now have code that relies on my module.

Comment: This helped and showed that my GOPROXY is being used, however I got 404 from Artifactory. See update #5 above.

Comment: @SamMorehouse, are you using a Virtual Repository or a Remote Repository as your GOPROXY? If you're using a remote repository, you'll also have to set up a virtual one, containing the remote repo pointing to GoCenter. I have a remote repository called `gocenter` and that repo is part of my virtual repo called `go2`. With that, I've set my GOPROXY as `http://<artifactoryserver>/artifactory/api/go/go2`

Comment: Ahhh! More undocumented features :) Reminds me of how helm doesn't work until you wrap everything in virtual repos.

Comment: I changed my remote repo to be called "gocenter-remote" and created a virtual repo called "gocenter" that includes only the remote repo. This still returns the "404 Not Found" when I try to "go get"

Comment: The "goc" binary downloaded the dependencies (goc get ...) but from https://gocenter.io, bypassing my virtual/remote repos. My gocenter-remote-cache repo is empty. The go.mod file was updated as you suggested @retgits with the indirect comment, which was removed once I built it. "goc build" built me a hello.exe

Comment: @SamMorehouse, the `goc` utility automatically assigns GOPROXY to be pointed to GoCenter and bypass all your Artifactory all together. A nice feature of `goc` is that when the module isn't in GoCenter it will get the sources from GitHub (or where ever the module source is) instead of failing the build. It's awesome you were able to build your app, though I'm still a little confused as to why your remote didn't work. I'll update my original answer to reflect both solution so others might benefit from it.

Comment: I finally got it to work by unsetting my office proxy. Local env was the issue after we got the module setup. To be clear, "go get ...." downloaded the files from my Artifactory instance, files are cached in Artifactory now.

Comment: Good to know that it's working. One update is that goc is not needed anymore. This change was made a few months back. go cli can be used to fetch go module versions from GoCenter and JFrog Artifactory. And JFrog CLI can be used to fetch module versions from JFrog Artifactory and also push module versions to JFrog Artifactory.